# How to make multiple Network calls and send result altogether after success only?

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I want to make two network calls and want to send result back to viewcontroller only when both the calls successfully completes. In following code I have used booleans `gotCountries` & `gotOcceans` to know if I got response. I want to remove these boolean flags and make sure I am sending both the result using completion block.

```
func fetchCountries() {
    countries = Network call to get countries success
    gotCountries = true // Boolean
    if gotCountries && gotOcceans {
        onCompletion?(self.countries, self.occeans)
    }
}

func fetchOcceans() {
    occeans = Network call to get occeans success
    gotOcceans = true // Boolean
    if gotCountries && gotOcceans {
        onCompletion?(self.countries, self.occeans)
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you get the countries, then check `if` countries is empty or not, if not then call the other function within it the fetchOceans one and once you received oceans the pass both oceans and countries in the completion handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use `DispatchGroup` for these kinds of situations to execute methods after the completion of multiple completion blocks. Here's an example:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

func fetchContriesAndOceans() {
    fetchCountries()
    fetchOcceans()
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
//      execute what needs to be executed after the completion of both methods here.
        onCompletion?(self.countries, self.occeans)
    }
}

func fetchCountries() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
//    dispatchGroup.leave() // Put this line in the completion of network call
}

func fetchOcceans() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
//    dispatchGroup.leave() // Put this line in the completion of network call
}
```